# Easy way to replace parts of code with other parts of code

Tags: javascript, string, html, loops

I'm making a small website for a game called League of Legends that compares matchup data (what champion counters a certain champs counters) and prints out results on a webpage. I'm using this html code that shows character portraits with `onClick()` to make them start a function when clicked

```
<a href="#" onClick="tristanaweak()"><img src="portraits/Aatrox_Square_0.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt=random></img>
<a href="#" onClick="tristanaweak()"><img src="portraits/Ahri_Square_0.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt=random></img>
<a href="#" onClick="tristanaweak()"><img src="portraits/Akali_Square_0.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt=random></img>
<a href="#" onClick="tristanaweak()"><img src="portraits/Alistar_Square_0.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt=random></img>
<a href="#" onClick="tristanaweak()"><img src="portraits/Amumu_Square_0.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt=random></img>
```

I've already manually put in the picture filenames (which was very tedious), but I still have to rename the `onclick()` values (tristanaweak) with the champion name (aatroxweak, ahriweak, etc.). I was thinking of doing this with a loop that edits text, but I don't know how I would go about doing this.

I'm fairly new to using Javascript, is there an easy way to rename all the `onClick="tristanaweak()"`'s in the html code to the first part of the png filenames in the same lines?

Comment: It looks like you have a separate function for each Champion? Why do that? You should have one function that takes a Champion as a parameter, and returns some form of data of that Champion's weakness or however you want to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should chose a different approach in my opinion. In javascript, you can also generate HTML dynamically using javascript function `document.createElement(string tagName)`.

So, one of two possible soulitions would be creating a new images with new event for every champion:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="hero_images">
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
var champions = [
   {
     name: "Veigar", 
     callback: function() {/**Whatever you wanna do in onclick**/}
   },
   {
     name: "Vladimir", 
     callback: function() {/**Whatever you wanna do in onclick**/}
   },
   {
     name: "Morgana", 
     callback: function() {/**Whatever you wanna do in onclick**/}
   }
];
//Now lets make an image for every champion:
var container = document.getElementById("hero_images"); //We'll put images in div I've defined in HTML above
for(var i=0; i<champions.length; i++) {  //Loop through "champions" which is an array
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href="#";
  a.onclick = champions[i].callback;  //Assign function from champion list to this <a>
  //Also create the image
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "portraits/"+champions[i].name+"_Square_0.png"; //I suppose image always have champion name in beginning
  img.alt = champions[i].name; //Alternative text for no-image users
  //Append image to link:
  a.appendChild(img);
  //Append <a> to <div>
  contained.appendChild(a);
}
```

But in fact, you should use a global function for champions and you should have champion stats defined in the `champions` I've used. Under such circumstances:

```
var champions = [
   {
     name: "Veigar", 
     stats: {
        inteligence: 666,
        strength: 1,
        /*..whatever you use...**/
     }
   }
];

for(/**imagine the prewious code here**/) {
   ...
   a.onclick=(function(i) {
     ShowHeroStatsOrWhatever(champions[i]);
   })(i); 
   ...
}
function  ShowHeroStatsOrWhatever(champion) {
    alert("Champions intelligence is "+champion.stats.inteligence);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using PHP. First, create a list of all the champions:

```
$champs = "aatrox,arhi,akali,alistar,amumu,...";
```

Then do an `explode` to separate each champion and store it as an element in an array:

```
$pieces = explode(",", $champs);
echo $pieces[0]; //this will return aatrox
echo $pieces[1]; //this will return ahri
```

Now you can use a `for` loop to `echo` the desired results:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($pieces);$i++) {
    echo '<a href="#" onClick="'.$pieces[$i].'weak()"><!--other stuff here--></a>';
}
```

In the end, the result will be something like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="aatroxweak()"><!--other stuff here--></a>
<a href="#" onClick="ahriweak()"><!--other stuff here--></a>
```

etc, etc. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this code but the loop doesn't seem to work. The echos outside of the loop work, but the loop doesn't print anything. I am not very familiar with PHP, do I have to change a part of the code?

Comment: No, it should work as is. Try echoing count($pieces) and see how many elements are in that array. Is that number what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

**Have you played around with jQuery `.replaceWith();`?**

> Description: Replace each element in the set of matched elements with
>   the provided new content and return the set of elements that was
>   removed.

**Or the straight up javascript way**  (which I use with in conjunction with jQuery over the above 90% of the time) with `.replace();`

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a
>   regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified
>   values are replaced.